# How/Should I cache a resource before performing a non-idempotent HTTP request on it?

Tags: android, rest, caching, realm

My client app (Android in this case) needs to POST to a collection. While I could simply POST and then save/cache the returned resource, I would like to save my version of the resource before it has reached the server.

Why attempt this? If the application is interrupted unexpectedly, I would like the resource marked as "POSTing" since the **HTTP 201** response handler was interrupted. This way the app can incorporate logic to check if my POST was successful before the ungraceful exit in order to avoid duplicate POSTs.

I am not sure if this practice is at all advised or standard, but that said, my next issue is how to implement the saving of the resource pre-POST. My client cache (currently using Realm for Android) has a primary key based on the server's primary key. I save the name of the last REST method issued on the resource and a boolean for whether it has finished.

How can I correctly persist and update the "partial/POSTing" resource since it does not yet have a valid primary key?

For example, consider a new User with schema:

[ primaryKey(server-based) | email | ... | RestMethod(GET/POST/etc) | lastRequestFinished ]

1. Store the partial creation:
   [ **someNumber** | "me@email.com" | ... | POST | false ]
2. Issue the **POST** (app could be interrupted here)
3. Handle **POST** response, update partial resource from earlier

[ 1091809 | "me@email.com" | ... | POST | true ]

Updating the primary key field is certainly not standard, can cause difficult bugs, and introduces non-intuitive logic. Is there a better way? Perhaps, I should have a client-side primary id and a server side primary id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have neglected to mention that I am also in control of the API. The most elegant solution I found was to convert all collection **POSTs** to instance **PUTs** by utilizing a new UUID field exposed to the client.

The API now has a private primary key field, but exposes a `client_id` UUID field. Like so:

```
class OldUser(DbModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()

class NewUser(DbModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    client_id = UUIDField(default=uuid4, unique=True)
```

In the User example, the android application now issues a PUT with a generated `client_id`. If I `PUT /users/<client_id>`, I can be assured that no matter the number of PUT requests I make, it will only affect single instance. The business logic for determining if I have the most up-to-date cache of that resource becomes greatly simplified. Outside my final suggestion in the original question, I did not see another way of accomplishing pre-request caching on non-safe HTTP methods without altering the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
// This will create a RealmObject without proxy which means the setters
// won't write data to Realm when you call them.
User user = new User();
user.setEmail("xxx");

// Next loop you get the primary key
...
user.setPrimaryKey(key);
// Then we can write it to Realm
realm.beginTransaction();
// Return value will be the RealmObject with proxy which means setters
// will write data to Realm without calling copyToRealmOrUpdate.
user = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve seems to me as overkill.It is probably important if the resource you are trying to post has no unique property say username or email address or something of that sort and this is hardly the case (it that is the case find a way to generate a unique id for the resource).As you are using **REALM** for persistent i encourage you to use a `@primaryKey` on the id and realm will ensure that no two `Model` will have that same field.

I strongly recommend you wait till you get success response from your back-end before persisting the resource. Still using realm just call `Model resource = new Model()` and it will not be persisted till you call `Realm#copyToRealm(RealmObject)` or its variants.

If you are not the one in control of the rest API, then communicate with whoever is in charge to return a particular response code whenever one attempts to create a resource that already exist, say a username which is registered is being sent again for another user as a new user. Then is up to you check the response code say **400 BAD REQUEST** then, it is your job to handle the error, maybe you will notify user that the email or user name already exists. Hop that helped.

Comment: You're right with the User example, as there is an obvious unique field that the API can simply check and return a 4xx response. I do, however, have other models that do not have an obvious unique field (outside of the primary key id from the server). I felt it was important for the client to behave well rather than having the API need to do a custom integrity check.